# After using openassets issue_asset() , the asset quantity is 0

Tags: open-assets

I am using openassets protocol issue_asset() function. After using the function, i call list_unspent(). The asset quantity field is all zero (see below). It means the issue_asset() function does not generate any assets. I have checked the return value of issue_asset(). It returns a valid transaction. Is there a reason why assets are not created?

The list_unspent() output is copied below:

```
[{"txid"=>"39e2b19597c5ab2e9d88ed7323a63a6de418dc3f04597ba5c520c5b968963b0e", "vout"=>0, "confirmations"=>119, "address"=>"mv3JUS2pmGj7QMXEtrpz4xtt3QuZdaqdE6", "oa_address"=>"bX61BibrAEkcoGbgbwUwAipoTP25jejEPFV", "script"=>"76a9149f4f15984e7ecbde4a14ace89d564d366fa206b788ac", "script_type"=>"pubkeyhash", "amount"=>"0.00000000", "asset_id"=>nil, "asset_quantity"=>"0", "asset_amount"=>"0", "account"=>"", "asset_definition_url"=>"", "proof_of_authenticity"=>false, "output_type"=>"uncolored", "solvable"=>true, "spendable"=>true}, 
{"txid"=>"6179fd02c7a031711d654068ef365e8d50c1aea57fc4a5554ca31de01bc47931", "vout"=>0, "confirmations"=>117, "address"=>"mv3JUS2pmGj7QMXEtrpz4xtt3QuZdaqdE6", "oa_address"=>"bX61BibrAEkcoGbgbwUwAipoTP25jejEPFV", "script"=>"76a9149f4f15984e7ecbde4a14ace89d564d366fa206b788ac", "script_type"=>"pubkeyhash", "amount"=>"0.00000000", "asset_id"=>nil, "asset_quantity"=>"0", "asset_amount"=>"0", "account"=>"", "asset_definition_url"=>"", "proof_of_authenticity"=>false, "output_type"=>"uncolored", "solvable"=>true, "spendable"=>true}, 
......
{"txid"=>"fe1920a5f71566e9ea1c5a61d0d818d64816170992df27b445003fba2a730fe8", "vout"=>0, "confirmations"=>114, "address"=>"mv3JUS2pmGj7QMXEtrpz4xtt3QuZdaqdE6", "oa_address"=>"bX61BibrAEkcoGbgbwUwAipoTP25jejEPFV", "script"=>"76a9149f4f15984e7ecbde4a14ace89d564d366fa206b788ac", "script_type"=>"pubkeyhash", "amount"=>"0.00000000", "asset_id"=>nil, "asset_quantity"=>"0", "asset_amount"=>"0", "account"=>"", "asset_definition_url"=>"", "proof_of_authenticity"=>false, "output_type"=>"uncolored", "solvable"=>true, "spendable"=>true}]
```

I also called get_balance(). The output is listed below. The is no assets too.

```
Balance [{"address"=>"n3hqP9u5kQydyqGcPy3NHcEWnzBKJnv3aX", "oa_address"=>"bXDfidKiRDtsKr5RySb9YwU968bMVMnf8Zr", "value"=>"0.00433888", "assets"=>[], "account"=>""}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is after issue_asset(), if the min_confirmation is 1, we have to mine the bitcoin block for one time. Then only after that, the asset can be seen in get_balance.